# Regex bug in Adobe Acrobat Javascript with shorthand character classes

Tags: javascript, regex, acrobat

Consider the following snippet:

```
var regex = /^\d+$/; // equivalent to new RegExp('^\\d+$');

console.println(regex.test('000'));  
console.println(regex.test('abc0')); 
console.println(regex.test('ddd'));
```

One would expect the output to be:

```
true
false
false
```

However, when I run it on Adobe Acrobat X, which runs JavaScript 1.8, it outputs:

```
false
false
true
```

What's going on here?

Comment: This is crazy, but try escaping the backslash.  `/^\\d+$/`, and see what you get.

Comment: That's odd. Does `^[0-9]+$` work?

Comment: [I can't reproduce this](http://jsfiddle.net/6ajVD/). I get the expected output. @FrankieTheKneeMan, escaping it isn't needed since it is a regex literal.

Comment: @Blender Yes, that works, but I'm trying to use the `\s` character class. This is just an example.

Comment: @vcsjones - 'Adobe Acrobat X'

Comment: @FrankieTheKneeMan That's it. Looks like there's a bug in Acrobat, because Foxit Reader gives me the expected results without the double backslashes.

Comment: Out of interest, how do you run it on Adobe Acrobat X? Is the script embedded in a PDF?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I'm using the interactive JS console to test it. This is actually part of a larger batch script that generates a report based on data from PDF files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's likely a result of string processing on the way to the Javascript interpreter, causing your `\d` to be interpreted as `d`.  An extra backslash (apparently) does the trick.

```
/^\\d+$/
```

Comment: This is very strange. Now `/^\d+$/` works. I have no clue what happened, but if the problem comes back I know how I can deal with it.